# Insert, update in single statement

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I have two table **table1** for adding details and **table2** for update id of table 1.My class look like this:

```
public bool SetData(List<Serialized> lstSerialized)
{
    string query = "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT Fid from table1 where Fid=@Fid)" +
                "INSERT INTO table1(" +
                "id, " +
                "Name, " +
                "Fid ,"+                     
                "Detail) OUTPUT INSERTED.id VALUES (" +
                "@id, " +
                "@Name, " +
                "@Fid )"+
               "@Detail)"+
                "ELSE UPDATE table1 SET Name= @Name,Detail= @Detail WHERE Fid = @Fid ";

    return Data.CreateSerialized(lstSerialized, query);
}

public bool CreateSerialized(List<Serialized> lstSerialized, string query)
{
    try
    {
        int Id=0;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                int id = GetMaxid();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = id
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = lstSerialized[0].Name;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Detail", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = lstSerialized[0].Detail;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fid ", SqlDbType.Int).Value = lstSerialized[0].Fid;

                con.Open();

                Id= (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                con.Close();
            }

            if (Id!=0)
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("update [table2] " +
                                                    "set Index=" + Id + " where " +
                                                    "[IndexID] = " + 9, con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Insertion was done successfully,but the update cannot work it shows error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Your code is missing a " on line `@Detail)"+`. Is this the cause or just an SO typo?

Comment: sql server 2012

Comment: There is a specific keyword for this [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try for cast object into int like this:

```
 object objId = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
 if (objId != null)
 {
  Id= (int)objId;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Update Query don't have any select statement. When

```
Id= (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

you try to cast id from this code it is unable to cast your id. Please handle this section you will get your result.